# How are data annotations transformed at runtime?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, data-annotations

In C# DataAnnotations allow you to specify some properties on classes, methods or properties.

My question is what exactly is happening behind the scene? Is it making use of the decorator pattern and wraps the class into another class that also contains the extra behaviour (eg. length of a string, range of a numeric etc) or it happens in a totally different manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Dan's answer, the best way to understand them is to create one...

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine (Foo.Bar.GetAttribute<ExampleAttribute>().Name);
    // Outputs > random name
}

public enum Foo
{
    [Example("random name")]
    Bar
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class ExampleAttribute : Attribute
{
    public ExampleAttribute(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static TAttribute GetAttribute<TAttribute>(this Enum enumValue)
            where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
        return enumValue.GetType()
                        .GetMember(enumValue.ToString())
                        .First()
                        .GetCustomAttribute<TAttribute>();
    }
}
// Define other methods and classes here
```

Answer (score 4):

The data annotations are attributes. Attributes are retrieved at run time via reflection. Take a look at this article.

[Attributes Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx)